# Android dropdown color picker

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, color-picker

I want to create a dropdown color picker, something like this (sorry for the ugly image):

[image: color dropdown picker]

I only need some colors (let's say 6) so I don't need a complete color picker, the dropdown will work fine.

I know I have to extend the array adapter for the Spinner and override **getDropDownView** and **getView**.

The thing I don't know is how to create a square box with a border and a solid background color.

I know that I can define my own shape inside drawable. Anyway I have to set the background color at runtime so I also need to change the view and set the correct background color.

Which is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: you can create shape drawable dynamically...have a look [here](http://www.betaful.com/2012/01/programmatic-shapes-in-android/)

Comment: I used your answed for the dropdown elements and the KEYSAN answer for the spinner text item. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to only background color you can use like this example.

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter<T extends BaseEntity> extends ArrayAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {    

    private final List<T> objects; // android.graphics.Color list

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<T> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.yourLayout, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

        View rowView = convertView;


        if (rowView == null) {
            // Get a new instance of the row layout view
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.activity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null);

            rowView.setBackgroundColor(objects.get(position));

        } else {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(objects.get(position));
        }


        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;


        if (rowView == null) {
            // Get a new instance of the row layout view
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.activity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null);

            rowView.setBackgroundColor(objects.get(position));

        } else {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(objects.get(position));
        }


        return rowView;
    }
}
```