# Android getting a list of colors from resource

Tags: java, android, xml, resources

I have a list of colours

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

(I took this list from another question someone asked)

What I want to do is get all the color names. I want the list so I can then populate the lot in a spinner. The pseudo code would be like this.

```
List ofColours = getListOfColors(R.color);
for(int i = 0 ; i < ofColours.size() ; i ++)
{
  String colour = getResources().getColor(ofColours.get(i));
  addColourToSpinner(colour);
}
```

What I want is the list of colours.
I hope that explains it Cheers for all the help

Comment: [Do I look like a Guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Comment: So.. what exactly is the question here?

Comment: How do I get a list of the colours!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13157347/1752867 that's similar your problem...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can access the list of colors using reflection:

```
Field[] fields = Class.forName(getPackageName()+".R$color").getDeclaredFields();
for(Field field : fields) {
    String colorName = field.getName();
    int colorId = field.getInt(null);
    int color = getResources().getColor(colorId);
    Log.i("test", colorName + " => " + colorId + " => " + color);
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it would not

Comment: Just curious (just read it again and realized it sounded critical). I never tried it on one, but it's a really cool trick

Comment: yeah...it looks a bit tricky but i can't think of any better way to do it

Comment: You **really** don't need Reflection for this.

Comment: @AdamArold I'm currious how you would answer the question.

Comment: Exactly like Siddharth Lele. That's the answer without Reflection.

Comment: but that does not really answer the original question, though it provides a nice hint on how to improve resources organization

Comment: I don't think that's even nice resource organization. Imagine you have 100 colors and you need to update color at 42.

Comment: @auselen: I take nothing away from _fiddler's_ answer, which I think is perhaps, a brilliant way of dealing with this question. I think my solution provides a simple alternative. Maintaining resources can be cumbersome. Agreed. But isn't that a _pit-fall_ of development? If everything was easy, we would probably be jobless eh? I would for sure. ;-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele There is always something more to do, yet again laziness is our virtue.

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is really weird.

Answer (score 6):

I got stuck doing this for my project. It took long time to make this and i hope it helps 
some people. I ended up combining an example from here

http://www.ipcas.com/blog/2011/12/android-color-picker/

and a color list provided from here

[Web colors in an Android color xml resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769762/android-color-xml-resource-file)

Just delete colors you dont need and make whatever you like. 
(Alot faster than making your own)

This is my Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">AppName</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="title_activity_visitor">Visitor</string>
<!--  Translation: Hint: White, Blue, Red...-->
<string name="accolor">Hint: White, Blue, Red&#8230;</string>


<integer name="colorGridColumnWidth">65</integer>




 <color name="AliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
 <color name="AntiqueWhite">#FAEBD7</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="Aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="Aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
 <color name="Azure">#F0FFFF</color>
 <color name="Beige">#F5F5DC</color>
 <color name="Bisque">#FFE4C4</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
 <color name="Black">#000000</color>
 <color name="BlanchedAlmond">#FFEBCD</color>
 <color name="Blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="BlueViolet">#8A2BE2</color>
 <color name="Brown">#A52A2A</color>
 <color name="BurlyWood">#DEB887</color>
 <color name="CadetBlue">#5F9EA0</color>
 <color name="Chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
 <color name="Chocolate">#D2691E</color>
 <color name="Coral">#FF7F50</color>
 <color name="CornflowerBlue">#6495ED</color>
 <color name="Cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
 <color name="Crimson">#DC143C</color>
 <color name="Cyan">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="DarkBlue">#00008B</color>
 <color name="DarkCyan">#008B8B</color>
 <color name="DarkGoldenrod">#B8860B</color>
 <color name="DarkGray">#A9A9A9</color>
 <color name="DarkGreen">#006400</color>
 <color name="DarkKhaki">#BDB76B</color>
 <color name="DarkMagenta">#8B008B</color>
 <color name="DarkOliveGreen">#556B2F</color>
 <color name="DarkOrange">#FF8C00</color>
 <color name="DarkOrchid">#9932CC</color>
 <color name="DarkRed">#8B0000</color>
 <color name="DarkSalmon">#E9967A</color>
 <color name="DarkSeaGreen">#8FBC8F</color>
 <color name="DarkSlateBlue">#483D8B</color>
 <color name="DarkSlateGray">#2F4F4F</color>
 <color name="DarkTurquoise">#00CED1</color>
 <color name="DarkViolet">#9400D3</color>
 <color name="DeepPink">#FF1493</color>
 <color name="DeepSkyBlue">#00BFFF</color>
 <color name="DimGray">#696969</color>
 <color name="DodgerBlue">#1E90FF</color>
 <color name="dullwhite">#FFDDDDDD</color>
 <color name="FireBrick">#B22222</color>
 <color name="FloralWhite">#FFFAF0</color>
 <color name="ForestGreen">#228B22</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Gainsboro">#DCDCDC</color>
 <color name="GhostWhite">#F8F8FF</color>
 <color name="Gold">#FFD700</color>
 <color name="Goldenrod">#DAA520</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="Gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="Green">#008000</color>
 <color name="GreenYellow">#ADFF2F</color>
 <color name="Honeydew">#F0FFF0</color>
 <color name="HotPink">#FF69B4</color>
 <color name="IndianRed">#CD5C5C</color>
 <color name="Indigo">#4B0082</color>
 <color name="Ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
 <color name="Khaki">#F0E68C</color>
 <color name="Lavender">#E6E6FA</color>
 <color name="LavenderBlush">#FFF0F5</color>
 <color name="LawnGreen">#7CFC00</color>
 <color name="LemonChiffon">#FFFACD</color>
 <color name="LightBlue">#ADD8E6</color>
 <color name="LightCoral">#F08080</color>
 <color name="LightCyan">#E0FFFF</color>
 <color name="LightGoldenrodYellow">#FAFAD2</color>
 <color name="LightGreen">#90EE90</color>
 <color name="LightGrey">#D3D3D3</color>
 <color name="LightPink">#FFB6C1</color>
 <color name="LightSalmon">#FFA07A</color>
 <color name="LightSeaGreen">#20B2AA</color>
 <color name="LightSkyBlue">#87CEFA</color>
 <color name="LightSlateGray">#778899</color>
 <color name="LightSteelBlue">#B0C4DE</color>
 <color name="LightYellow">#FFFFE0</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="Lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="LimeGreen">#32CD32</color>
 <color name="Linen">#FAF0E6</color>
 <color name="Magenta">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="Maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="MediumAquamarine">#66CDAA</color>
 <color name="MediumBlue">#0000CD</color>
 <color name="MediumOrchid">#BA55D3</color>
 <color name="MediumPurple">#9370DB</color>
 <color name="MediumSeaGreen">#3CB371</color>
 <color name="MediumSlateBlue">#7B68EE</color>
 <color name="MediumSpringGreen">#00FA9A</color>
 <color name="MediumTurquoise">#48D1CC</color>
 <color name="MediumVioletRed">#C71585</color>
 <color name="MidnightBlue">#191970</color>
 <color name="MintCream">#F5FFFA</color>
 <color name="MistyRose">#FFE4E1</color>
 <color name="Moccasin">#FFE4B5</color>
 <color name="NavajoWhite">#FFDEAD</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="Navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="OldGold">#CFB53B</color>
 <color name="OldLace">#FDF5E6</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="Olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="OliveDrab">#6B8E23</color>
 <color name="Orange">#FFA500</color>
 <color name="OrangeRed">#FF4500</color>
 <color name="Orchid">#DA70D6</color>
 <color name="PaleGoldenrod">#EEE8AA</color>
 <color name="PaleGreen">#98FB98</color>
 <color name="PaleTurquoise">#AFEEEE</color>
 <color name="PaleVioletRed">#DB7093</color>
 <color name="PapayaWhip">#FFEFD5</color>
 <color name="PeachPuff">#FFDAB9</color>
 <color name="Peru">#CD853F</color>
 <color name="Pink">#FFC0CB</color>
 <color name="Plum">#DDA0DD</color>
 <color name="PowderBlue">#B0E0E6</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="Purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="RosyBrown">#BC8F8F</color>
 <color name="RoyalBlue">#4169E1</color>
 <color name="SaddleBrown">#8B4513</color>
 <color name="Salmon">#FA8072</color>
 <color name="SandyBrown">#F4A460</color>
 <color name="SeaGreen">#2E8B57</color>
 <color name="Seashell">#FFF5EE</color>
 <color name="Sienna">#A0522D</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="Silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="SkyBlue">#87CEEB</color>
 <color name="SlateBlue">#6A5ACD</color>
 <color name="SlateGray">#708090</color>
 <color name="Snow">#FFFAFA</color>
 <color name="SpringGreen">#00FF7F</color>
 <color name="SteelBlue">#4682B4</color>
 <color name="Tan">#D2B48C</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="Teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="Thistle">#D8BFD8</color>
 <color name="Tomato">#FF6347</color>
 <color name="Turquoise">#40E0D0</color>
 <color name="Violet">#EE82EE</color>
 <color name="Wheat">#F5DEB3</color>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
 <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="WhiteSmoke">#F5F5F5</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="Yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="YellowGreen">#9ACD32</color>


<array name="colorNameList">
    <item>AliceBlue</item>
    <item>AntiqueWhite</item>
    <item>Aqua</item>
    <item>Aquamarine</item>
    <item>Azure</item>
    <item>Beige</item>
    <item>Bisque</item>
    <item>Black</item>
    <item>BlanchedAlmond</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>BlueViolet</item>
    <item>Brown</item>
    <item>BurlyWood</item>
    <item>CadetBlue</item>
    <item>Chartreuse</item>
    <item>Chocolate</item>
    <item>Coral</item>
    <item>CornflowerBlue</item>
    <item>Cornsilk</item>
    <item>Crimson</item>
    <item>Cyan</item>
    <item>DarkBlue</item>
    <item>DarkCyan</item>
    <item>DarkGoldenrod</item>
    <item>DarkGray</item>
    <item>DarkGreen</item>
    <item>DarkKhaki</item>
    <item>DarkMagenta</item>
    <item>DarkOliveGreen</item>
    <item>DarkOrange</item>
    <item>DarkOrchid</item>
    <item>DarkRed</item>
    <item>DarkSalmon</item>
    <item>DarkSeaGreen</item>
    <item>DarkSlateBlue</item>
    <item>DarkSlateGray</item>
    <item>DarkTurquoise</item>
    <item>DarkViolet</item>
    <item>DeepPink</item>
    <item>DeepSkyBlue</item>
    <item>DimGray</item>
    <item>DodgerBlue</item>
    <item>FireBrick</item>
    <item>FloralWhite</item>
    <item>ForestGreen</item>
    <item>Fuchsia</item>
    <item>Gainsboro</item>
    <item>GhostWhite</item>
    <item>Gold</item>
    <item>Goldenrod</item>
    <item>Gray</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>GreenYellow</item>
    <item>Honeydew</item>
    <item>HotPink</item>
    <item>IndianRed</item>
    <item>Indigo</item>
    <item>Ivory</item>
    <item>Khaki</item>
    <item>Lavender</item>
    <item>LavenderBlush</item>
    <item>LawnGreen</item>
    <item>LemonChiffon</item>
    <item>LightBlue</item>
    <item>LightCoral</item>
    <item>LightCyan</item>
    <item>LightGoldenrodYellow</item>
    <item>LightGreen</item>
    <item>LightGrey</item>
    <item>LightPink</item>
    <item>LightSalmon</item>
    <item>LightSeaGreen</item>
    <item>LightSkyBlue</item>
    <item>LightSlateGray</item>
    <item>LightSteelBlue</item>
    <item>LightYellow</item>
    <item>Lime</item>
    <item>LimeGreen</item>
    <item>Linen</item>
    <item>Magenta</item>
    <item>Maroon</item>
    <item>MediumAquamarine</item>
    <item>MediumBlue</item>
    <item>MediumOrchid</item>
    <item>MediumPurple</item>
    <item>MediumSeaGreen</item>
    <item>MediumSlateBlue</item>
    <item>MediumSpringGreen</item>
    <item>MediumTurquoise</item>
    <item>MediumVioletRed</item>
    <item>MidnightBlue</item>
    <item>MintCream</item>
    <item>MistyRose</item>
    <item>Moccasin</item>
    <item>NavajoWhite</item>
    <item>Navy</item>
    <item>OldGold</item>
    <item>OldLace</item>
    <item>Olive</item>
    <item>OliveDrab</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
    <item>OrangeRed</item>
    <item>Orchid</item>
    <item>PaleGoldenrod</item>
    <item>PaleGreen</item>
    <item>PaleTurquoise</item>
    <item>PaleVioletRed</item>
    <item>PapayaWhip</item>
    <item>PeachPuff</item>
    <item>Peru</item>
    <item>Pink</item>
    <item>Plum</item>
    <item>PowderBlue</item>
    <item>Purple</item>
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>RosyBrown</item>
    <item>RoyalBlue</item>
    <item>SaddleBrown</item>
    <item>Salmon</item>
    <item>SandyBrown</item>
    <item>SeaGreen</item>
    <item>Seashell</item>
    <item>Sienna</item>
    <item>Silver</item>
    <item>SkyBlue</item>
    <item>SlateBlue</item>
    <item>SlateGray</item>
    <item>Snow</item>
    <item>SpringGreen</item>
    <item>SteelBlue</item>
    <item>Tan</item>
    <item>Teal</item>
    <item>Thistle</item>
    <item>Tomato</item>
    <item>Turquoise</item>
    <item>Violet</item>
    <item>Wheat</item>
    <item>WhiteSmoke</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
    <item>YellowGreen</item>
</array>








 <array name="colorNumberList">
    <item>@color/AliceBlue</item>
    <item>@color/AntiqueWhite</item>
    <item>@color/Aqua</item>
    <item>@color/Aquamarine</item>
    <item>@color/Azure</item>
    <item>@color/Beige</item>
    <item>@color/Bisque</item>
    <item>@color/Black</item>
    <item>@color/BlanchedAlmond</item>
    <item>@color/Blue</item>
    <item>@color/BlueViolet</item>
    <item>@color/Brown</item>
    <item>@color/BurlyWood</item>
    <item>@color/CadetBlue</item>
    <item>@color/Chartreuse</item>
    <item>@color/Chocolate</item>
    <item>@color/Coral</item>
    <item>@color/CornflowerBlue</item>
    <item>@color/Cornsilk</item>
    <item>@color/Crimson</item>
    <item>@color/Cyan</item>
    <item>@color/DarkBlue</item>
    <item>@color/DarkCyan</item>
    <item>@color/DarkGoldenrod</item>
    <item>@color/DarkGray</item>
    <item>@color/DarkGreen</item>
    <item>@color/DarkKhaki</item>
    <item>@color/DarkMagenta</item>
    <item>@color/DarkOliveGreen</item>
    <item>@color/DarkOrange</item>
    <item>@color/DarkOrchid</item>
    <item>@color/DarkRed</item>
    <item>@color/DarkSalmon</item>
    <item>@color/DarkSeaGreen</item>
    <item>@color/DarkSlateBlue</item>
    <item>@color/DarkSlateGray</item>
    <item>@color/DarkTurquoise</item>
    <item>@color/DarkViolet</item>
    <item>@color/DeepPink</item>
    <item>@color/DeepSkyBlue</item>
    <item>@color/DimGray</item>
    <item>@color/DodgerBlue</item>
    <item>@color/FireBrick</item>
    <item>@color/FloralWhite</item>
    <item>@color/ForestGreen</item>
    <item>@color/Fuchsia</item>
    <item>@color/Gainsboro</item>
    <item>@color/GhostWhite</item>
    <item>@color/Gold</item>
    <item>@color/Goldenrod</item>
    <item>@color/Gray</item>
    <item>@color/Green</item>
    <item>@color/GreenYellow</item>
    <item>@color/Honeydew</item>
    <item>@color/HotPink</item>
    <item>@color/IndianRed</item>
    <item>@color/Indigo</item>
    <item>@color/Ivory</item>
    <item>@color/Khaki</item>
    <item>@color/Lavender</item>
    <item>@color/LavenderBlush</item>
    <item>@color/LawnGreen</item>
    <item>@color/LemonChiffon</item>
    <item>@color/LightBlue</item>
    <item>@color/LightCoral</item>
    <item>@color/LightCyan</item>
    <item>@color/LightGoldenrodYellow</item>
    <item>@color/LightGreen</item>
    <item>@color/LightGrey</item>
    <item>@color/LightPink</item>
    <item>@color/LightSalmon</item>
    <item>@color/LightSeaGreen</item>
    <item>@color/LightSkyBlue</item>
    <item>@color/LightSlateGray</item>
    <item>@color/LightSteelBlue</item>
    <item>@color/LightYellow</item>
    <item>@color/Lime</item>
    <item>@color/LimeGreen</item>
    <item>@color/Linen</item>
    <item>@color/Magenta</item>
    <item>@color/Maroon</item>
    <item>@color/MediumAquamarine</item>
    <item>@color/MediumBlue</item>
    <item>@color/MediumOrchid</item>
    <item>@color/MediumPurple</item>
    <item>@color/MediumSeaGreen</item>
    <item>@color/MediumSlateBlue</item>
    <item>@color/MediumSpringGreen</item>
    <item>@color/MediumTurquoise</item>
    <item>@color/MediumVioletRed</item>
    <item>@color/MidnightBlue</item>
    <item>@color/MintCream</item>
    <item>@color/MistyRose</item>
    <item>@color/Moccasin</item>
    <item>@color/NavajoWhite</item>
    <item>@color/Navy</item>
    <item>@color/OldGold</item>
    <item>@color/OldLace</item>
    <item>@color/Olive</item>
    <item>@color/OliveDrab</item>
    <item>@color/Orange</item>
    <item>@color/OrangeRed</item>
    <item>@color/Orchid</item>
    <item>@color/PaleGoldenrod</item>
    <item>@color/PaleGreen</item>
    <item>@color/PaleTurquoise</item>
    <item>@color/PaleVioletRed</item>
    <item>@color/PapayaWhip</item>
    <item>@color/PeachPuff</item>
    <item>@color/Peru</item>
    <item>@color/Pink</item>
    <item>@color/Plum</item>
    <item>@color/PowderBlue</item>
    <item>@color/Purple</item>
    <item>@color/Red</item>
    <item>@color/RosyBrown</item>
    <item>@color/RoyalBlue</item>
    <item>@color/SaddleBrown</item>
    <item>@color/Salmon</item>
    <item>@color/SandyBrown</item>
    <item>@color/SeaGreen</item>
    <item>@color/Seashell</item>
    <item>@color/Sienna</item>
    <item>@color/Silver</item>
    <item>@color/SkyBlue</item>
    <item>@color/SlateBlue</item>
    <item>@color/SlateGray</item>
    <item>@color/Snow</item>
    <item>@color/SpringGreen</item>
    <item>@color/SteelBlue</item>
    <item>@color/Tan</item>
    <item>@color/Teal</item>
    <item>@color/Thistle</item>
    <item>@color/Tomato</item>
    <item>@color/Turquoise</item>
    <item>@color/Violet</item>
    <item>@color/Wheat</item>
    <item>@color/WhiteSmoke</item>
    <item>@color/Yellow</item>
    <item>@color/YellowGreen</item>


</array>
</resources>
```

Next i used the ColorPickerDialog provided by

http://www.ipcas.com/blog/2011/12/android-color-picker/

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

    public ColorPickerDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setTitle("ColorPickerDialog");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.color_picker);

        GridView gridViewColors = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewColors);
        gridViewColors.setAdapter(new ColorPickerAdapter(getContext()));

        // close the dialog on item click
        gridViewColors.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ColorPickerDialog.this.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

with this as well.

```
public class ColorPickerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    // width of grid column
    int colorGridColumnWidth;
    //array of color values
    int[] colorNumberarray; 
    // array of color names
    String[] colorNameArray; 

    public ColorPickerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        // defines the width of each color square
        colorGridColumnWidth = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.colorGridColumnWidth);


        //fill  colorNumberarray with values from the colorNumberList Array in strings.xml  
        colorNumberarray = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colorNumberList);
        //fill  colorNameArray with values from the colorNameArray Array in strings.xml 
        colorNameArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorNameList);

        //Show results in verbose Log
        for (int i = 0; i < colorNumberarray.length; i++) {
            Log.v("Test", colorNumberarray[i] + "");
            Log.v("Test", colorNameArray[i] + "");


        }



    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        // can we reuse a view?
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            // set the width of each color square
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(colorGridColumnWidth, colorGridColumnWidth));

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setBackgroundColor(colorNumberarray[position]);
        imageView.setId(position);

        return imageView;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return colorNumberarray.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will save people some time.

Next you launch the dialog,

```
 IBcolorpicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Dialog dialog;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Clicked!
            // Make a new dialog.
            dialog = new ColorPickerDialog(Visitor.this);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rename colors according to the general scheme

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="color1">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="color2">#FFFF00</color>
 ...
</resources>
```

And then iterate over them by name

```
var i = 1
while (true) {
    val colorId = resources.getIdentifier("color$i", "color", packageName)
    if (colorId != 0) {
        // color exists
        ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, colorId)
    } else {
        break
    }
    i++
}
```

No reflection

Comment: This was a really good approach to avoid reflection. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply create two arrays in in your `strings.xml` or `arrays.xml`. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="items">
        <item>white</item>
        <item>yellow</item>
        <item>fuchsia</item>
        <item>red</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="values">
        <item>#FFFFFF</item>
        <item>#FFFF00</item>
        <item>#FF00FF</item>
        <item>#FF0000</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

You can follow a simple example on developer.android.com here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html.

This is another tutorial: http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?start=1

That should get you started.

Comment: There is no color preview in the IDE in this case