# How to read a color using R.color by using a variable ID

Tags: android

I have the following colors defined in color.xml. The color names are BC1, BC2, BC2 etc. There are 15 such color names defined. The last color is BC15.

```
<color name="BC1">#39DD02</color>
<color name="BC2">#FEA200</color>
<color name="BC3">#21C3F3</color>
........
<color name="BC15">#21F3F3</color>
```

In my code I am trying to get the color with the following code:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.BC1)
```

The above code works fine. Now, I want to use this code inside a loop so that I can pick the color based on a counter value, so that I can read colors one by one, as in the following psedo-code.

```
for(colorID=1;colorID<=15;colorID++)
{

     int businessColor=ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.<colorID> )

     //Do something with the value inside businessColor 
}
```

In the above code, how do I use the colorID counter to read colors one by one

I tried to write the following. (Assuming that I can get hexdecimal value from an array)

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), Color.parseColor("#636161"))
```

But the above code shows me error "**Expected resource of type color**".

Comment: You can use [`getIdentifier` from `Resources`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) to fetch that identifier for a string. Something like `getResources().getIdentifier(NameOfYourColor, "color", getPackageName())` should work to get the id for `getColor`.

Comment: Define an array in `values/arrays.xml` and iterate over that

Comment: With respect to `getIdentifier`, be sure to read this note in the docs - "Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name."

Comment: I am surprised to see a down-vote. This question was posted after going through various threads in this site, but I couldn't find a solution. Can anyone explain the reason for down vote, so that I take care in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Define your color resources

2.Add them to an array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
     <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
     <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
     <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
     <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
     <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>


        <array name="array_name">
            <item>@color/white</item>
            <item>@color/yellow</item>
            <item>@color/fuchsia</item>
            <item>@color/red</item>
            <item>@color/silver</item>

        </array>
    </resources>

int[] colorArray= context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_name);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
    paint.setColor(colorArray[i]);

}
```

you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13344457/5188159) too

Comment: Your solution definitely works for Paint.setColor(colorArray[i]), but if I use colorArray in the statement ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), colorArray[colorIndex]), then, during runt time, it fails with error resource not found. It seems ContextCompat.getColor() is not able to recognize it as a color resouce. Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend you not to have flying references to Context there and there. Activity is a subclass of Context. You can use directly this or NameOfActivity.this to access the context. try it like this -> ContextCompat.getColor(this ,colorArray[colorIndex]); and update me

Comment: I am executing this code inside a fragment. I tried your suggestion, but 'this' is identified as wrong argument by the IDE.

Comment: getActivity() if u use a fragment ,->getActivity() is at least a method on Fragment, to get the activity it is attached to.

Whenever a context is needed in an instance method of an activity, you can use ->this.