# Changing a layout background and status bar color

Tags: android

I m making a simple single screen app
and I m trying to change background color of layout randomly from 11 colors
on button click, i know how to use random method but cant figure out how to store 11 colors in array and how to access them
[This like may tell you what i want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344191/android-getting-a-list-of-colors-from-resource)
this is the layout i want to change color of

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/bg"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">
```

Here my colorarray.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--bg color-->
<color name="color1">#7e3ff2</color>
<color name="color2">#ff6e39</color>
<color name="color3">#f2366e</color>
<color name="color4">#e800c3</color>
<color name="color5">#b402ee</color>
<color name="color6">#01abff</color>
<color name="color7">#00d5a0</color>
<color name="color8">#00d5c7</color>
<color name="color9">#7763cf</color>
<color name="color10">#e3e17c</color>
<color name="color11">#c7984b</color>

<array name="background">
    <item>@color/color1</item>
    <item>@color/color2</item>
    <item>@color/color3</item>
    <item>@color/color4</item>
    <item>@color/color5</item>
    <item>@color/color6</item>
    <item>@color/color7</item>
    <item>@color/color8</item>
    <item>@color/color9</item>
    <item>@color/color10</item>
    <item>@color/color11</item>
</array>
```

**Edit**
Since above problem is now solved 
now how can i change status bar color accordingly to same color as background

```
<!--status bar bg color-->
<color name="darkcolor1">#3b00e0</color>
<color name="darkcolor2">#e64705</color>
<color name="darkcolor3">#c80050</color>
<color name="darkcolor4">#bd00ae</color>
<color name="darkcolor5">#7300e0</color>
<color name="darkcolor6">#0c89db</color>
<color name="darkcolor7">#009d5c</color>
<color name="darkcolor8">#009d5c</color>
<color name="darkcolor9">#443cb6</color>
<color name="darkcolor10">#b6ae39</color>
<color name="darkcolor11">#ceac54</color>


<array name="statusBarBg">
    <item>@color/darkcolor1</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor2</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor3</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor4</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor5</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor6</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor7</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor8</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor9</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor10</item>
    <item>@color/darkcolor11</item>
</array>
```

Comment: Did you try `setBackgroundColor`?

Comment: yup ,but how can i acces the color from color.xml in java code

Comment: You may do it like `ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent)`.