# How to apply different font styles to difeerent items in the spinner?

Tags: android, fonts, android-spinner

In my app,I have a spinner which displays Sunday, Monday,Tuesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday.I want to display each item in different font style.i.e Sunday in Times New Roman font,Tuesday in Calibri font,Wednesday in Arialic Hollow font like that.I am taking those fonts in fonts folder created in assets.Please help me how to do it.

My main activity is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
 public class AndroidCustomSpinner extends Activity{

    String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
            "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, DayOfWeek);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }

}
```

my row.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/icon" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> 
<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/weekofday" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

and my main.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <TextView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="Spinner" /> 
 <Spinner 
  android:id="@+id/spinner" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Write a customAdapter and in getView and getDropDownView methods change the font of textview based on your requirement..

Comment: Just like a font drop down in Microsoft Word right ?

Comment: ya in the same way that ms word appears

Comment: here an example for sytle of every line on listview.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/13157347/1752867

Comment: I want to change the font for each item.I know how to change the font for total spinner items.But i need to each spinner item separately.And I am using layouts here.

Answer (score 2):

In the AdapterArray use this to format

```
public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    //inflate the view
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_rows, parent, false);
    TextView dayView=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dayView);//view where you show days
    if(position==1)//if 1 is for sunday
    {
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TimesNewRoman.ttf"); 
        dayView.setTypeface(face); 
    }
    else if(position==2)//if 1 is for monday
    {
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/someotherFont.ttf"); 
        dayView.setTypeface(face); 

    }
   return row;
}
```

You could make Array of the Days and formats and iterate through them in the function instead of if else statement

Comment: Please give me an idea how to change Sunday then i will proceed

Comment: It is good.But in my program how should i use it.I am not getting that.

Comment: Create your own custom arrayadatper and override the getCustomView as in the answer, 
now create instance of the custom adatper and set it to spinner, please refer the tutorials or step to step process, Thank you