# Create spinner dropdown with two lines of different fonts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, dropdown

I have a spinner that naturally has multiple rows. For each row, I need to have two lines, each of different font. How might I do that?

For example, pretending the lines have different font

> LINE ONE OF FONT 1
>
> line two of font 2

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22854703/6570665) should definitely help you.

Answer (score 2):

create an Adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter` and override `getDropDownView()`

```
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.spinner_location_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_first_view);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_second_view);
        textView1.setText("LINE 1");
        textView2.setText("LINE 2");
        return view;
    }
```

Then you can give it any layout you want.